# how reliable is the GPS Speed on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps, accelerometer

I am developing a Windows Phone 7 app and I want to tell the user how fast they are going.  Something simple like...

Current Speed: 20 km/h
Max Speed: 33 km/h
Average Speed: 25 km/h

I seem to have two options:
1) use accelerometer
2) use GPS

I'm wondering if people have suggestions on which method to use.

I would prefer to use the GPS (as that is much simpler to extract), but I know that GPS position is often not accurate for various reasons, but how accurate is the speed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speed and direction tend to be more accurate than absolute position - this is because speed and direction are *not* calculated by tracking successive position measurements (as you might expect).  Rather, these values are generally estimated by using the Doppler shift of the satellite signals, which for technical reasons is less affected by the factors that tend to distort absolute position.

By contrast, the accelerometer probably won't be very useful for measuring speed, as speed and acceleration are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

GPS is going to be very accurate.  The exact same data is coming from the satellites, and it is used for myriad GPS applications.  It takes reception from three of them to get good data.  It is possible for users to only have two or one satellite available.  If you only have one satellite, the only thing you can get is the time.

The limitations in accuracy can depend on the receiver, so it might vary based on the actual hardware on the phone rather than the Win7 phone OS.

I can't speak to the code that Microsoft wrote that interprets the data, but I'm sure they did as well as any other software company would.  I have not heard of any flaws in that area specific to MS.

Comment: I'd agree if you had said "GPS is *not* going to be very accurate" - depending on the part of the constellation that's currently above the horizon, and other factors (urban canyons are rather bad for reception), smartphone GPS tends to be *somewhat* accurate - give or take tens/hundreds of meters (hundreds of feet); not much below that. If you have a map, you can mask this e.g. by trying to pin the user to the closest road, but again you have to be aware that you're essentially guesstimating. You are correct that this is not specific to any one company, but inherent in the system.

Comment: also, IIRC, you need *at least* four satellites to get a fix, more with low-accuracy receivers such as most smartphones have. The algorithm is trying to triangulate you in 4D (space+time), as the GPS signal is basically a stream of time signals, and your position is calculated from the known satellite positions and the time shift between received signals.